# Best practice for nested async requests

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, nested

I'm using a third party api and Axios to get the customer's cart that returns a list of product ids and the quantity of each product. I'm then looping through the ids for the full product info.

It's all working but I'm no promise expert and I'd love some advice on how to improve this code. Should the second `then` be split out? Or is bundling all this together fine in terms of best practices?

Additional context - I'm using Next.js and this will be called in `getStaticProps`

```js
export const getCartProducts = async () => {
  const data = await axios
    // get most recent cart of user
    .get('https://example.com/api/carts', {
      params: {
        display: 'full',
        output_format: 'JSON',
        'filter[id_customer]': '[0]',
        sort: '[id_DESC]',
        limit: '1',
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(process.env.API_AUTH + ':'),
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((cartResponse) => {
      const cart = cartResponse.data.carts[0];

      // return product ids and quantity
      const cartMeta: TCartItem[] = cart.associations.cart_rows.map(
        (item: any) => {
          const { id_product, quantity } = item;
          return {
            id: id_product.toString(),
            quantity,
          };
        }
      );

      return cartMeta;
    })
    .then(async (cartMeta: TCartItem[]) => {
      const items: (TCartProduct | undefined)[] | void = await axios
        // fetch product data for each id
        .all(cartMeta.map((item: TCartItem) => getProductById(item.id)))
        .then((products) =>
          products.map((product: TProduct | null) => {
            if (product) {
              const productCartMeta = cartMeta.find(
                (meta) => meta.id === product?.id
              ) as TCartItem;

              // return data needed for product display on cart page
              return {
                ...product,
                quantity: productCartMeta?.quantity ?? 0,
              };
            }

            return;
          })
        )
        .catch((error) => handleError(error));

      return items;
    })
    .catch((error) => handleError(error));
  
  // called in Next.js `getStaticProps` so needs to default to null
  return data ?? null;
};
```

Comment: It will get much more readable/ maintainable if you use `async/ await`.

Comment: @Mushroomator They are (just not for everything that they could be) so that comment might need a bit more explanation.

Comment: Remove `.then()` altogether, use only `await`